# XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8080/user/fileupload. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot

I am trying to upload a file using angularjs.I have spring boot appication running in my local machine.I am running angularjs page using node http server.But I am getting above error.I saw some solutions like running disbale security command for chrome like this..chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files...did not work...some people saying run app from server.I am running it using nodejs simple http-serve.Still getting same error.Don't know where is the issue.This is my angular code....

```
uploadFileToUrl: function(file){
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', file);

$http.post("http://localhost:8080/user/fileupload", fd, {
transformRequest: angular.identity,
headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
})

.success(function()
alert("success");
})

.error(function(){
alert("error");
});

}
```

This is my server code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fileupload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile   uploadfile) {
try {

saveUploadedFiles(Arrays.asList(uploadfile));

} catch (IOException e) {
return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
return new ResponseEntity("Successfully uploaded - "
+ uploadfile.getOriginalFilename(), new HttpHeaders(),HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

I am able to upload file from postman.But not for angularjs code.Anybody can tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: What what port is your angular app running ?

Comment: @karthik localhost:8081

Comment: That is the issue. deploy both the apps on the same port, and things should be fine. If not, please refer https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: @karthik...thanks for your suggestion..ran both on same port..it's working now